# C# invalid column name problem but is different from others

Tags: c#, sql

Hello i have a table called Card_tbl with a cell CardID. The problem is that when i insert only numbers like **12345** they are uploaded in the database, but when i use mix letters like **Q1234R** it will say `INVALID COLUMN NAME Q1234R` I tried many things to fix it but no success.
**THE CELL IS ON VARCHAR(50)** this is my code

```
Con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Card_tbl values(" +txtCardNumber.Text+")", Con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Admin Successfully Added!");
            Con.Close();
            populate();
            //updateroomstate();
            Clean();
```

the error is shown here `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use a sqlparameter to pass the value. This prevents a lot of issues, like the one you have and sql injection

Comment: Anyway, I recommend looking into "prepared statements" aka "parameterized queries" as this should 1) solve your problem and 2) protect you from SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @Llama the thing is the same query works for other tables where i declare varchar(50) and both character and number are inserted in the database with no problem.

Comment: You should also  have `using` blocks on `Con` and `cmd`, and don't block the thread with a `MessageBox` while the connection is open

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this instead

Insert into Card_tbl(CardID) values('" +txtCardNumber.Text+"')"

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Comment: No didnt work still says the same error..

Comment: Are you definitely adding single quotes around the value? Aside from that, as Hans says, this would be safer done using a ask Parma passed into an existing stores procedure.

Comment: [Obligatory XKCD reference](https://xkcd.com/327/). Please don't give bad advice like this. SQL injection problems shouldn't be a problem these days, but people writing queries the way you have in your answer just propagates the problem.

Comment: @DeanO'Brien you were correct i forgot to add the signle quotes, Thank you for your help!

Comment: @noreply Test Dean's solution with the following text (exactly like this) in `txtCardNumber.Text`: `'); DROP TABLE Card_tbl; -- byebye table!`. Note that you should make a backup of your database first.

Comment: Apologies for answering the question that the O P asked. I didn't write the query, I simply pointed out why his query was failing. Much the same as you have done in the comments above.

Comment: You could have answered correctly by using parameters. The column name is a good addition, but not enough for a safe solution

Comment: Ok, noted for future posts. Only just started answering on SO. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

#### Solution

The correct solution is to use prepared statements. You've said the column is a `varchar(50)` so:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("yourconnectionstring"))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Card_tbl VALUES (@cardNumber)", conn))
    {
        // we specify type VarChar and size 50, because your column is a varchar(50)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@cardNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtCardNumber.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

I would also recommend that you specify the column name for the insert:

```
INSERT INTO Card_tbl (CardId) VALUES (@cardNumber) -- I've assumed that the column is called CardId
```

#### Why do we need parameterized queries / prepared statements?

The reason we need prepared statements is because the user could enter something malicious in the query, forcing your server to execute queries that you didn't intend.

If you have a query like this, SQL Server will do the insert and then drop the table:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES ('hello'); DROP TABLE MyTable; -- comment
```

This is a multi-statement query, meaning that the INSERT will be done first, and then the DROP TABLE will be executed. The `--` denotes a comment, and everything after that in the query is discarded.

Now, if you build a query like `"INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES ('" + someUserInput + "')"`, how could a malicious user make this query more like the previous one? Simple: enter SQL into their input.

Suppose `someUserInput` is `'); DROP TABLE MyTable; -- comment` then your query will become:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(''); DROP TABLE MyTable; -- comment')
```

Like this, a malicious user can perform an extremely destructive operation on your database, bypass login pages, expose secret information, etc. This is a huge risk for your application.

Prepared statements work by separating the query text from the parameter values. Because they're not part of the query, they can't be interpreted as SQL. It also means that binary data types can be sent to the server as binary rather than as text. Example: `DateTime`.